# How to select a div that has a class and a specific id

Tags: jquery

I have a html markup with some `<div>` elements like this:

```
<div id="1" class="classic">i am text</div>
<div id="2"  class="classic">i am text</div>
<div id="3" class="classic">i am text</div>
<div id="4" class="classic">i am text</div>
```

How can I select a div that has this class and a specific id like 1?

Can you show me how to do this in jQuery?

Comment: *id* attributes are required to start with a letter in order to be valid.

Comment: i directly write code so i make confusion for them. see i clear them.

Comment: that's better, but you still need to change those IDs so they don't begin with a digit. Try <div id="d1"> ... <div id="d2"> .. etc.

Comment: i can't change it if i do it then my task is not complete on the time and i need to change everything in code so i can't change anything in mock up.

Comment: @user268701 Well you're skating on very thin ice. You won't be able to style the individual DIVs using a selector and, although jQuery appears to work, there are no guarantees that what you produce will continue to work. If it's just a mock-up, you might be able to get away with it - just make sure you don't do this in production code!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#ID.class')
```

e.g.

```
$('#one.classic')
```

is what you want; please create valid HTML first!

Answer (score 4):

I think the syntax you actually want is this:

```
$('#d1.classic')
```

That's grabbing by ID but only if it has the class.  The presence or absence of the space is important.  Also, ID's do need to start with a letter, they should not be purely numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Since ids are unique, you could theoretically just use `$('#1')`

Comment: Only within the page; the poster MIGHT be using the same jQuery across multiple pages, but only want to match the combination of class and id

Comment: ... or, the OP may want the selector to fail if it doesn't find both: `#id.Selected`.

Comment: @Kobi: yup, that's exactly what I meant :)

Answer (score 1):

`$('#1.classic')`
 except you should have something like `$('#one.classic')`
 because ID attributes need to start with a letter.

Also you have an `and` in your HTML that really shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

since all elements should have unique IDs, `$('#1')` should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Id, then its supposed to be unique, so $('#1') will work, but the inner document.getElementById('1') will be a lot faster..

If you need to use jQuery, you can use $(document.getElementById('1')) and will be faster anyway...

If you need to select class and id anyway, you should use $('#1.classic')